# How to search with Spotlight more effectively

Tags: macos, search, spotlight, desktop-search

I'm used to using various flags to modify the results of Google searches, to only show results from a particular site, or only certain kinds of files.

For example you can restrict Spotlight searches to only look for pdf files like this example, when I'm looking for a pdf cheatsheet for using YUI's grid system css framework on my computer.

```
YUI grid kind:pdf
```

I'd be amazed if Apple's Spotlight didn't have loads of other handy flags to fine tune a search in the same way - what tricks do you use, or where do you look to find more tips to improve your Spotlight-fu?

Answer (score 13):

#### Spotlight menu and Finder

- `name:filename`
- `kind:kindle` (`kind:mobi` and `*.mobi` cannot be used)
- `kind:image`
- `date:today` (`date:week` and `date:month` don't work)
- `date:12/31/11` (other formats like `date:2011-12-31` don't work)
- `date:12/1/11-12/31/11`
- `kind:mp3 AND bitrate:<192000`

#### [Common metadata attribute keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_metadata/mditem/common_metadata_attribute_keys)

`mdls -name $attribute $file` shows the value of a single attribute and `mdls $file` lists all attributes.

- `kMDItemContentType`: the uniform type identifier like `public.plain-text`
- `kMDItemContentTypeTree`: the UTI and its parent UTIs
- `kMDItemDisplayName`: the name of a file without an extension if its extension is set to be hidden
- `kMDItemDurationSeconds`: for example the duration of audio or video files
- `kMDItemFinderComment`: the Spotlight comment that can be set in Finder's information windows
- `kMDItemFSContentChangeDate`: modification date
- `kMDItemFSCreationDate`: creation date
- `kMDItemFSInvisible`: the visibility of a file
- `kMDItemFSName`: the name of a file with a filename extension
- `kMDItemFSSize`: the size of a file in bytes
- `kMDItemKind`: a kind description like HTML document
- `kMDItemLastUsedDate`: date last opened
- `kMDItemNumberOfPages`: for example the number of pages in a PDF file
- `kMDItemPageWidth`: for example the width of a PDF document in points
- `kMDItemPath`: the full path of a file
- `kMDItemTextContent`: contents of the file
- `kMDItemTitle`: for example the title of a PDF document or a website
- `kMDItemURL`: for example the URL of a webloc file
- `kMDItemWhereFroms`: a URL a file was downloaded from

#### [mdfind query expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html)

- `mdfind . -onlyin ~/Pictures`
- `mdfind 'kMDItemFSContentChangeDate == $time.this_week(-1)'`
- `mdfind 'kMDItemTextContent == "*expose*"cd'` (ignore case and diacritics)
- `mdfind 'kMDItemFSSize >= 5000 && kMDItemFSSize <= 5005)'`
- `mdfind 'kMDItemFSContentChangeDate >= $time.iso(2012-04-13T13:44Z)'`
- `mdfind 'kMDItemFSCreationDate >= $time.now(-3600)'`
- `mdfind 'kMDItemKind == "*movie" && kMDItemPixelHeight >= 720'`

Comment: [Digging Deeper: Mastering Spotlight in OS X - Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/03/digging-deeper-mastering-spotlight-in-os-x/)

Comment: tag: ... also works now.

Answer (score 4):

There's a whole article regarding this subject [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/132788/2008/04/spotlight2.html). In short:

- you use boolean operators, such as AND, OR, NOT
- applying quotation marks will search for exactly the phrase you want
- using `name: keyword` will only search file names
- `author: keyword` allows you to search files by file author (Spotlight will find only files produced by programs that save this attribute—Mail, iChat, Word, Excel, Pages, Numbers, and a few others)
- you can use `date:today`, `created: date` and `modified: date` to search for files by a particular date
- you can refine your search to only find certain file types using `kind: filetype` (the article I linked to contains all the possible file types you might need)