# Text search tool in Mac for programmer

Tags: macos, search

I have used Total Commander in Windows to search string in files, view results and browse source tree.

In mac, I have not found similar tool. Does anybody have good suggestions?

I have tried Spotlight, but that does not search through all files.

Grep is too slow to use (navigating search results is pain).

Comment: Is this of any help? http://superuser.com/questions/72774/search-through-text-files-in-mac-os-x (seems somewhat similar)

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight is configurable. Check system preferences.
You could also use Google Desktop:
http://desktop.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might use [Find & Replace It!](http://www.dprog.ch/home/products/find_and_replace_it/) This utility can search any text file for a given string or regular expression. This is a shareware but the nice thing is that the free demo version lets you search for text, only the replacements (files modifications) are unavailable. Hence, if you only need to find something in your source code, it might help.

This software detects the charset of your files (most of the time). That's convenient when you have both some HTML/XML files using UTF-8 encoding and PHP scripts encoded with ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/) for this. It allows you to filter in searches.

If I understand your question, that is what your looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight doesn't search/index all files by default, but you can [explicitly tell it to search System files](http://www.macworld.com/article/60711/2007/10/spotsyssearch.html) and can also [get it to index excluded directories](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2005050222125145).

Answer (score 0):

There's [Disk Order](http://www.likemac.ru/). It's supposed to be the Total Commander for Mac... But I have never tried it, and I don't know if it would be a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[ack-grep](http://betterthangrep.com/) might be what you want:

> ack is a tool like grep, designed for programmers with large trees of heterogeneous source code.
>
> ack is written purely in Perl, and takes advantage of the power of Perl's regular expressions.