# Searching Mac Through Terminal?

Tags: linux, mac, terminal

are there any commands to search your Mac using terminal? I tried usin grep to search but it seems somewhat unresponsive and nothing comes up.

For example, I would type "grep Files" (A folder name) and it just prints a blank line and nothing happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search through text files in Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/72774/search-through-text-files-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: I'm interested in searching through all types of files; Not necessarily excluding text files but not only text files.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can also use the `mdfind` command in order to perform a search with Spotlight.
More info [here](http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/spotlight-on-command-line.html).

Use `mdfind -name searchterm` in order to retrieve files with the name `searchterm`.
Use `mdfind searchterm` to perform a search on file name and content.

Answer (score 43):

If you just want to find files with a certain name, use `find`

The man page can be found [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) or by typing `man find` at the terminal prompt.

Basically, find will recursively look for a file meeting criteria you specify. The easiest example:

`find . -name file_name -print`

That will search for a file named "file_name" starting in the current directory and searching below and print the files with that name.

`find ~ -name ".DS_Store" -delete`

That will find all the .DS_Store files and delete them.

You can search by name, regex, date. You can act on the file in any Unix way with the `-exec` predicate.

You can also use find as the start of a more complex pipeline of actions. Example:

`find . -type f -print | egrep -i '\.m4a$|\.mp3$'`

Will find all the files with extensions .m4a or .mp3

`find . -type f -print | egrep -i '\.m4a$|\.mp3$' | wc -l`

Will give you a count of those files.

Comment: If `-print` is the only predicate, it can be omitted; also, there's simple globbing available.  Thus finding all of the `.txt` files under a directory `foo` would be done with `find foo -name \\*.txt`

Comment: @yoshi: That is absolutely false. Typing `find .` IS recursive from the cwd. Try typing `find .` in your root directory!

Comment: My bad could swear it wasn't recursive but maybe server has chocked -shrug-

Answer (score 5):

If you want to search through a whole folder, just use -r on grep:

```
grep -r pattern folder/to/search
```

With find, you can also use xargs:

```
find folder/to/search -name '*.txt' | xargs grep pattern
```

or to make sure that you search two files at a time and therefore have the filenames specified:

```
find folder/to/search -name '*.txt' | xargs grep -n2 pattern
```

Answer (score 3):

[`grep`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html) expects both a pattern and a filespec. If one is missing then it uses what is passed as the pattern, and waits for the data to search via standard input.

If you want to use a more complex filespec then use [`find`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html).

```
find ~ -name '*.txt' -exec grep -q 'secret' {} \; -print
```

Comment: I just basically want it to find files that have the name that I enter into the command.

Comment: In that case you don't need to use the `-exec` predicate in `find`.